# React-Admin - adding material ui theme overrides specific css selector as a global

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, material-ui, react-admin

In React-Admin, I'm trying to apply certain css code inside my Material UI theme as a global attribute. Right when I'm creating my theme, I've been added those lines inside my overrides:

```
overrides: {
    "@global": {
        "[class*='RaLayout-content']": {
            overflow: "auto !important",
            maxWidth: "100vw !important",
        },
    },
```

In the entire admin I have many classes like: `RaLayout-content-4`, `RaLayout-content-221`, `RaLayout-content-31`, which are generated by the React-Admin, and I want to apply those css lines in every element that contains the `RaLayout-content` class.

Because of class names minimization of Heroku deploy, I cannot write those css lines in my index.css cause they'll not apply after the minimization.

Here's how I implemented them before, inside my index.css file (which is working only in development mode):

```
[class*="RaLayout-content"] {
  overflow: auto !important;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

Notice: I've been also trying to add the MuiCssBaseLine with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can override the theme with

```
overrides: {
  RaLayout: {
    content: {
      // your overrides
    },
  },
  ...
}
```